# Sending notifications from android device to another android device by using Firebase

Tags: java, android, firebase-cloud-messaging, chat

I am building app i implement in it chat to connect between users the problem is i need to notify users when they receive messages

i try this https://codelabs.developers.google.com/codelabs/firebase-android/#4 but it is send notification from Firebase console to Devices this is not what i need . i need make users send to others notification

..

the actual result is iam not able to know how to send notification between users

Comment: Do you want a device (mobile) to communicate with another device directly like trough IP addresses?

Comment: iam not know which best method to do this .. tell me which is the best method

Comment: There is no way to get a hold of a device IP adress, the ISP is usually doing som funky routing so the device can only connect out and no connection can be established IN

Comment: iam not understand you iam beginner in this explain please what you write :''D

Comment: The Firebase codelab you tried is one way to do it.

Comment: @Erik but why iam try send messages notifications not showing

Comment: Check LogCat output in Android studio for Firebase error messages

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In this video, everything is explained :

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=voIFz8aE9eE&list=PLGCjwl1RrtcQ3o2jmZtwu2wXEA4OIIq53&index=23

Resume :

1)Create a node called "Notification".

2)Create HashMap with what you need to send in it. 
Like this by example :

```
 HashMap<String, Object> chatNotif = new HashMap<>();
        chatNotif.put("from", currentUserID);
        chatNotif.put("message", yourmessage);

        FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("Notifications").child(YOURFRIENDID).push().updateChildren(chatNotif);
```

3) Create cloud function

In the video, this guys show you how to write a cloud function that will be trigered everytime you write something to this path :
*Notification/$userID/$notificationkey*

In this function, you will retrieve the data inside the nofication and simply send what you want to the user $userID with the method sendToDevice